# PHP - get specific element form each sub array without looping

Tags: php

In php is there a way to get an element from each sub array without having to loop - thinking in terms of efficiency.

Say the following array:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'element1' => a,
        'element2' => b
    ),
    array(
        'element1' => c,
        'element2' => d
    )
);
```

I would like all of the 'element1' values from $array

Comment: Looping is going to be a lot more efficient than any alternatives, unless you know exactly how many entries are in the top-level of your array and you want to hard-code a line of code for every element.... so 200 entries = 200 lines of code, with no option to change the number of entries without changing your code, and saves you all of 2.75 picoseconds to avoid looping - bad on a whole load of counts, good on none

Comment: 200 lines of code even pasting will take more than 2.75 picoseconds. Unless there is some specific logic behind this which wasn't stated in the question, there is no point in not looping.

Comment: How do you want the 'element1's returned to you?  An array?  A string?

Comment: @PhillSparks not important as I can deal with that later in my code.

Comment: If you're already running PHP 5.5, then the new array_column() feature can give you this

Comment: @MartyWallace well it kind of is important, because if you want a string then I'd recommend [array_reduce](http://uk1.php.net/array_reduce), if you want an array I'd recommend [array_map](http://uk1.php.net/array_map), and if you want to modify the existing array I'd suggest [array_walk](http://uk1.php.net/array_walk).  All of which will loop internally however.

Comment: @MarkBaker Unfortunately not, but this is exactly what i need :(

Comment: …and even array_column() uses loops internally

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of different functions that can operate on arrays for you, depending on the output desired...

```php
$array = array(
    array(
       'element1' => 'a',
       'element2' => 'b'
   ),
   array(
       'element1' => 'c',
       'element2' => 'd'
   )
);

// array of element1s : array('a', 'c')
$element1a = array_map(function($item) { return $item['element1']; }, $array);

// string of element1s : 'ac'
$element1s = array_reduce($array, function($value, $item) { return $value . $item['element1']; }, '');

// echo element1s : echo 'ac'
array_walk($array, function($item) {
    echo $item['element1'];
});

// alter array : $array becomes array('a', 'c')
array_walk($array, function(&$item) {
    $item = $item['element1'];
});
```

Useful documentation links:

- [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)
- [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)
- [array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)**.

Try code below...

```
$arr = $array = array(
    array(
       'element1' => a,
       'element2' => b
   ),
   array(
       'element1' => c,
       'element2' => d
   )
);

print_r(array_map("getFunc", $arr));

function getFunc($a) 
{ 
    return $a['element1']; 
}
```

See **[Codepad](http://codepad.org/pprRR5wS)**.

**But I think array_map will also use loop internally.**

Comment: I prefer this notation: `$func = function(){echo $a['element1']."\n";} array_map($func, $arr);` (working as of PHP 5.3).

Comment: Why array_map?  array_map's callbacks should return a value, and array_map itself will then return an array.  Your example here would be better with array_walk

Answer (score 2):

If you're running PHP 5.5 (currently the beta-4 is available), then the following

```
$element1List = array_column($array, 'element1');
```

should give $element1List as an simple array of just the element1 values for each element in $array

```
$array = array(
    array(
       'element1' => a,
       'element2' => b
   ),
   array(
       'element1' => c,
       'element2' => d
   )
);

$element1List = array_column($array, 'element1');
print_r($element1List);
```

gives

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => c
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without loop? Recursion!

```
$array = array(
        array(
                'element1' => 'a',
                'element2' => 'b'
        ),
        array(
                'element1' => 'c',
                'element2' => 'd'
        )
);

function getKey($array,$key,$new = array()){
    $count = count($array); 
    $new[] = $array[0][$key];
    array_shift($array);

    if($count==1)
        return $new;

    return getKey($array,$key,$new);
}

print_R(getKey($array,'element1'));
```

As I understood from Wikipedia [Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) is not a loop.